# Why is my class not populating this attribute?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python, a couple days actually, and I'm having a very small problem that is driving me crazy. I'm trying to make a text based game, and I want to assign a vocation to the player based on their input. It all works fine apart from the stat changes. For instance, when the player selects Warrior, I want their strength to change. As such, I made a separate python file for the warrior class and imported it. That being said, for some reason, when I set up this if statement to change the strength in the player class, I can't seem to get it to work. I just have no idea what's going wrong with the if statement here. I've tried 'is' and '==' and everything, but I don't know what the issue is!

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.inventory = [items.Axe(),
                      items.HealingPotion(),
                      items.CrustyBread()]

    self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
    self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
    self.hp = 100
    self.hp_max = 100
    self.hp_min = 0
    self.gold = 20
    self.victory = False
    self.char_vocation = vocation.Warrior()
    self.strength = 8
    self.dexterity = 8
    self.intelligence = 8

    if self.char_vocation == vocation.Warrior():
        self.strength = 12
    else:
        self.strength = self.strength
```

Comment: What does `vocation.Warrior()` return?

Comment: Can you share how  you are calling this class?

Comment: Side note: what exactly is the point in `self.strength = self.strength`?

Comment: Can a Player's char_vocation change?
Is there more than one option for char_vocation?
Do you know the character's char_vocation when an instance of Player is made?
Can a Player have no char_vocation?

Comment: Your `if self.char_vocation ...` never evals to `True` becaus you are instantiating a new `.Warrior()` object. Read up on [`isinstance(object, classinfo)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is not being set because you are not checking if self.char_vocation is an instance of the class Warrior, you are asking if it is equal to a brand new instance of warrior.
This code will do what you ask:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.inventory = [items.Axe(),
                      items.HealingPotion(),
                      items.CrustyBread()]

    self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
    self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
    self.hp = 100
    self.hp_max = 100
    self.hp_min = 0
    self.gold = 20
    self.victory = False
    self.char_vocation = vocation.Warrior()
    self.strength = 8
    self.dexterity = 8
    self.intelligence = 8

    if isinstance(self.char_vocation, vocation.Warrior):
        self.strength = 12
```

If you know the vocation in the beginning, and that vocation never changes, it may make sense to refactor this
to:

```
def make_player(vocation_class):
  class Player(vocation_class):
    def __init__(self):
      self.inventory = [items.Axe(),
                      items.HealingPotion(),
                      items.CrustyBread()]

      self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
      self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
      self.hp = 100
      self.hp_max = 100
      self.hp_min = 0
      self.gold = 20
      self.victory = False
      self.dexterity = 8
      self.intelligence = 8
      super().__init__(self)

  return Player()

class UnsetVocation:
  def __init__(self):
    self.strength = 8

class Warrior:
  def __init__(self):
    self.strength = 12

p = make_player(UnsetVocation)
assert p.strength == 8

p = make_player(Warrior)
assert p.strength == 12
```

Comment: Oh god thank you so much, I knew it would be something like that! You are my hero!